# Equivalence in the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

If a monotone sequence is bounded it converges. Does convergence implies monotonicity and boundedness?

Comment: Nope, think of sequence 0,1/2,0,1/4,0,1/6,... We're every odd member is 0 and every nth even number is 1/(2^n) this sequence is bounded and converges to 0 but is not monotone

Comment: What if a sequence is convergent and not monotone and we only know that it is bounded? Can we somehow obtain convergence? Because convergence asks for both, boundedness and monotonicity.

Comment: Yep convergence implies bounded but bounded only implies convergent subsequence

Comment: So there is no way to prove convergence with only proving boundedness? And the sequence might be convergent but not monotone am I right? So you have to choose some other way of proving convergence of such a sequence?

Comment: The whole reason why monotone and blindness together imply convergence is because it essentially means this sequence since is going one direction (increasing or decreasing) and is bounded it must be "piling" up at one point. Bounded was alone is it enough because it could just be alternating constantly like sin(x) and monotone is not enough because it could just increase/decrease to infinity

Comment: Proving boundedness  only allows convergent subsequence and my example above is an example of a non monotone convergent sequence

Comment: Sorry about awful grammar and spelling typing on phone lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that every convergent sequence is bounded (we can bound the infinite number of terms near the limit, leaving us with a finite number of terms at the start of the sequence), but not every convergent sequence is monotonic. For example, consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ given by
$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$
It should be clear that $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ since $1/n\to 0$. However, we're alternating between negative and positive terms, so it's neither increasing nor decreasing!